# "Windows Error Reporting" is missing from the services' list

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, services

I'm a Windows 10 user. Lately I'm dealing with frequent BSOD episodes (more or less twice a day) that don't appear to be triggered by any specific action of mine; actually they happen mostly when I'm AFK.

The BSOD states that an error report is being written somewhere. So I downloaded a software called "BlueScreenView" that should let me easily browse through those reports. And to my surprise there was no report at all!

I made a little bit of research and found out that Windows 10 is supposed to write those reports in minidump files (*.dmp) hosted in `C:\WINDOWS\MiniDump\` or in a big file in the `C:\WINDOWS\` directory.

I have reports in none of those. I checked what where the settings on my computer, because maybe it was writing the minidumps somewhere else, and found out that the directory [was correctly set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMQkP.png).

[image: sysdm.cpl]

I kept on invastigating until I found out that the service responsible for actually writing those minidumps should be "Windows Error Reporting". Some instructions I found online suggested to check if something was going on with it. So I looked for it in the services' list and... it's not there.

[image: It's not there at all]

As you see my Windows 10 installation is in italian language, so the service might have a different name. But I checked all that list, one element at a time, and I didn't find anything remotely similar to "Windows Error Reporting", which in italian should be "Segnalazione Errori Windows".

So here I am, trying to figure out what can I do to have that service to work in my hardware, so that I can retro-engineer what's causing the BSOD episodes and find a solution for that.

Comment: It is possible for Windows to crash (Blue Screen) and not write a minidump file. I have seen this happen.  Try updating all Drivers and BIOS to see if that helps.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc It says that no damages were found in the components' archive

Comment: What did SFC say?

Comment: Is it possible that that service name was localized to Italian?  The main reason I ask is that my English version has several other "Windows blahblahblah" services that your list does not.  I can also see that Microsoft localizes *some* of them by your image.  Open a cmd.exe prompt.  Type `net start WerSvc`.  You will get (probably in italian) "The service name is invalid" if it doesn't exist.  You will get (in Italian) "Access is denied" if it does.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: I get a "System error 5: Access denied". I thought about a localization too, but as I mentioned I went through the whole list and I didn't find anything similar, to me at least.

Comment: @harrymc no problems found.

Comment: @John I updated the video card driver. The CPU one is up to date. I'm doing the Windows updates now. We'll see if the BSODs will leave or what.

Comment: If it continues, I suggest doing [Repair Install with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) using the latest Windows version. This is the same as doing a major Windows update, just mind your backups.

Comment: "Servizio Segnalazione errori Windows" or something like that?  Anyways.. the service isn't your problem.  A "falsa pista" I believe or "red herring" as we say in English.

Comment: So, several days have passed. I have updated all the Intel drivers and the video card too. Nothing's changing. I keep on getting these errors more or less a couple of times a day, and the PC is still not writing them in the minidump. Is there some other kind of report that Windows 10 writes when going on through a BSOD? Is there some other reason why the report shouldn't be written?